# Exception message without param

Tags: c#, exception, listbox

**General information:**

I have created my own ListBox which extends `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` and added a method `AddItem(value : string)`  which makes sure that `value` meets the requirements and does not exist in the `ListBox`.

In case the `value` does not meet the requirements or already exists in the `ListBox` I throw an `ArgumentException`.

I also pass the constructor of ArgumentException both, the message plus the param that caused the exception.

```
if (this.Items.Contains(value))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("\"{0}\" already in list.", value), "value");
}
```

**My issue:**

As I pass both, message & paramName, I get both by accessing `Message` which is not my purpose. I want the message itself only.

> Value is empty.
>
> Parametername: value

Is there a way to receive the message only?

> Value is empty.

Comment: Did you try to pass only the message part? The ArgumentException constructor has also an overload that uses only the Message

Comment: I did and it works then but why the heck "Message" gives you both information if both defined? If I am in need of the paramName I'd simply access `ParamName`. This probably never will be logged but just in case I want to add the paramName here as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code of the property Message in the `ArgumentException` class

```
public override String Message
{
    get {
        String s = base.Message;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_paramName)) {
            String resourceString = Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_ParamName_Name", m_paramName);
            return s + Environment.NewLine + resourceString;
        }
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

As you can see, internally the property first retrieves the string value from the base class (Exception) then, checks if you have passed a parameterName in the constructor of the class. If this is the case then parameterName is added to the first part of the string and returned to the caller.

This explains why you get the two strings together. The logic behind this is in the minds of the MS developers. However I find it correct, `Message` is the complete text of your exception.

A simple extension of the class ArgumentException could be written to achieve the separation of Message from parameterName

```
public class ArgumentExceptionMessage : ArgumentException
{
    private string _message;
    public ArgumentExceptionMessage(string message, string paramName) 
        : base(message, paramName)
    {
        _message = message;

    }
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return _message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, the only way to achieve this is to write my own `ArgumentException` and extend it by `System.Argument.Exception`?

Comment: I see. Alright, thank you for your quick response it kinda helped me though it's not the answer I was hoping for :D